# Using Jquery show hide on Dropdown Menu in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I want to hide or show some form elements on the basis of value selected in dropdown menu. But I can't understand how to use jquery on this. This is my view page.

```
<body>
<?php
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('What do you want to eat?'))."<br>";
echo '<div class='vegetables'>;
echo $this->formRow(.....);
....
....
echo '</div>';
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
?>
</body>
```

Say, I have created a dropdown which has options 'Fruits' and 'Vegetables'. On selecting vegetables, div 'vegetables' of form should show up else it should be hidden. How do I do that in Zend Framework2.

Comment: Do you want to use jquery for show/hide?..

Comment: Create a div wrapper around the fields which should be shown or hidden. Then onChange of the dropdown, hide or show the wrapper.

Comment: Yes, I want to use show() hide() functions to display form elements on the basis of dropdown option selected. I am using Zend Framework 2. I don't know how to do it on this index.phtml page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
jQuery('#dropdownid').change(function(){

if(jQuery(this).val() == 'Fruits')
   jQuery('formparttoshow').show();
else
jQuery('formparttohide').hide();

})
```